# CSS if statements... is it right?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I'm new with the conditional CSS.  My question is, is it right to use it for dealing with cross-browsers issues?

For example:

```
#header
{
    [if IE 7] width: 600px;
    [if Webkit] width:300px;    
}
```

---

> Editor's note: OP is most likely using this: http://www.conditional-css.com/

Comment: Where did you get that example?

Comment: Check out http://www.conditional-css.com/advanced

Comment: @BalaR: Interesting! I've never heard of this. It should be noted in the question to attract the appropriate answers.

Comment: I've never see this before, so I don't believe that would be valid or work at all.

Comment: I got from the same link above..."Editor's note:" :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use conditional statements for the actual CSS files (or classes) but on the html.

Like this for example:

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<link href="css/layoutIE6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

This is written on the html file, not the CSS file!

The format you posted I think doesn't actually work and I bet it doesn't validate so it is not standard.

Comment: Thanks...jackJoe! I saw your kind of solution on the web...The question is how can I do the same thing with one CSS file...and not with different files for each case

Comment: @BorisD well, depends on having a standards method or not. The solution I suggested is within standards, if you want a non-standards, go for the "hack" method, like adding an underscore to the class property, ex: `_font: Arial` (works with IE6 at least), or use the "star" hack (add an asterix to the class property , works with IE7. Mind you that this method is very difficult to troubleshoot in a big CSS file!

Comment: Thanks again Captain Jack! Well you really helping me with my knowledge in CSS...can you give me some examples for the so called "hack" method...the thing with the underscore and "star"...

Comment: @BorisD the examples are simple, just add an underscore to the CSS property you would like to style for IE6 (first add the regular property: `font: Geneva;` and then specify for IE6: `_font: Arial;`), for IE7 use the "*" instead of the underscore. But this method is very limited, I suggest you go for the conditional statements.

Answer (score 6):

It's become common to use variations of this technique for IE, I believe it was made popular by [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) [citation needed]:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html lang="en-us" class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html lang="en-us" class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html lang="en-us" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en-us"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Now you can target elements **without IE hacks** in your main CSS files like so:

```
.ie6 .header li {
    /* some ie6 only styles here */
}
```

To me, this is a lot more maintainable than using separate stylesheets, but suffers the very mild setback of other browsers reading (but not applying) the IE styles.

If you are having trouble with Webkit, you are most likely doing *something* wrong. Not Absolutely, but it's *very* likely.

EDIT: Many browsers allow proprietary extensions that let you set rules that will only apply to that browser. Example:

```
-moz-property {}
-webkit-property {}
-o-property {/* Opera */}
```

Note that this does not mean you can apply ***any*** CSS property, you will have to see what is available.

Best reference I could find quickly: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/vendorspecific

<sub>SO Editors, feel free to replace this link if there is a better reference</sub>

Comment: Note that this was copy/pasted from HTML5Boilerplate source, I'm not certain why `<!--[if gt IE 8]>` is used to target non-IE browsers... Worth investigating, I'm not entirely familiar with the ins and outs of IE conditional comments.

Comment: Anyway, this is such a simple and clever method ;)

Comment: I agree, much better than IE hacks and extra CSS files. It's such a pain to try and update two separate files instead of seeing the conditional rules right there next to the normal ones.

Comment: Very good and intresting code...The question is how deal with other browsers?

Comment: @BorisD: Write good, valid CSS! Other browsers usually "have it right", and any styles you need to add to "fix" one won't affect the other (like adding a `clear` property or something that you should have had in the first place). Rarely should you have problems in standards compliant browsers.

Answer (score 1):

As to the validity of your statements, jackJoe's got a nice answer. 
But, it's not generally good practice.  It's a better idea to, as far as layout goes, get a good layout that works cross browser and not muck around with browser specific layout problems. Instead, worry about feature-specific issues. 
There are definitely times when you just can't fix an IE6 issue and at which point you probably should apply some browser specific code so you don't give yourself a headache.

In general, though, that's just not even a good idea.

Side Note: Why in the name of Tim Berners-Lee are you still trying to support IE5?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not,
You Can try these

For IE 7 & 8:
`width: 600px\9;`
 For IE10 :
`width:300px\0/;`

For all browsers:
`width: 600px;`

But if you want it on all three browsers separately IE,GC,FF then use it like this
`width:300px; width: 600px\9; width:300px\0/;`
I Think this is what you were looking for!