# how to validate IE 7/8 CSS hacks?

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I've used the conditional comments technique for my IE6/7/8 CSS "hacks", so that the main CSS file (with the common/standard classes) validates correctly (isolating the IE "hacks" in separate CSS files).

Something like this:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link href="css/layoutIE7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Now I've started using conditional comments to add a class to the `<body>` (please read this answer: [CSS if statements... is it right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101314/css-if-statements-is-it-right/6101515#6101515) ) and then target the class that needs a "hack" in my main CSS file, this way I can have only one file.

The problem with this method is that because I have everything in one file, it means that in case I have something as "simple" as the CSS3 `opacity` property:

```
.mydiv {
    opacity:0.6;
}
```

The IE "counterpart" (i.e.: "hack") will have to be something like:

```
.mydiv {
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
 }
```

Which doesn't validate correctly.

I know the method I was using before still had this problem, but since you could test the site in a non-IE environment, it always validated (because I made sure the main CSS was valid), now since I'm trying to have one single CSS it doesn't validate (for the reasons explained).

My question is how to add this "hacks" in a way that the validator considers it valid?

Hopefully the answer should be CSS only.

Comment: Just let it be invalid. It does not matter if you break validation, provided that you know what you're doing. Every CSS parser under the sun is familar with IE's `filter` syntax, so it will never break anything.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. If a non-standard CSS property is present in the style sheet, it won't validate. Nothing one can do to change that.

I think you'll have to choose either valid CSS, or using multiple style sheets.

Answer (score 5):

CSS validation is overrated. Honestly.

As long as your markup validates, your CSS is constructed well and the site works in all your target browsers then you've done your job. The falacy that CSS must validate is long dead.

Comment: Maybe so, but it's worth the author of the question knowing. There are no fixes to CSS hacks (not that his example is even a "hack" by definition, actually), but that's already been covered.

Comment: I tend to disagree - having valid HTML and CSS is an excellent thing for a QA process, even though many of the rules don't make sense. A green light is much better than a red light that needs close looking at to interpret whether it's okay or not to drive on anyway

Comment: Ok, but what does having valid CSS actually achieve? A little green light on your developer toolbar to make you feel proud and more at ease? Valid HTML is a must and I'll never disputed that. CSS's sole purpose is to style a document and if your document renders correctly in your target browsers then you've done your job. QA should consider the approaches to the solution. The document should be well-formed with no obvious errors, but not using vendor prefixes or invalid properties in order to achieve validation isn't worth it. A CSS document should be easy to navigate, read, edit and re-use.

Comment: @amustill The main point of having valid CSS is detecting syntax errors, broken nesting etc. before a site gets deployed. In a complex environment with a huge build process, having a little green light that catches those kinds of things can be *very* helpful.

Comment: Syntax errors and broken nesting is what I meant by "obvious errors". Worrying that your vendor prefix makes the CSS document invalid is silly, though.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to validate CSS hacks. If you want your CSS to be valid, go back to the conditional comments solution you were using before. Regarding CSS validation, many Web Designer gurus such as Andy Clarke or Zeldman have repeatedly said CSS should be used as helpful tool, not as a rule. It does not add any practical value besides helping you correct syntax errors.